Getting rid of the Livebox
At work, we are using a Orange Pro fiber offer with the Livebox Pro. Of course, this is Pro in the name only, nothing about it is Pro.
Thus, I plan on using a real pro router (for instance: https://eu.store.ui.com/eu/en/category/all-unifi-cloud-gateways/products/udm-se) but the Livebox cannot be set as bridge only. I have two options :

double routing : from WAN to Livebox and from Livebox to my router. It would work but it's sad to keep using this low quality hardware.
connect WAN directly to the new router.

Two questions :

would the Unify router be able to access internet without the Livebox?
the fiber is plugged on the Livebox with a RJ-45 port. I could use the new router's RJ-45 WAN port but it will deteriorate the bandwidth. Or I use the SPF -> RJ-45 adapter (https://eu.store.ui.com/eu/en/category/cloud-gateways-large-scale/products/uacc-cm-rj45-mg?variant=uacc-cm-rj45-mg) but would it work to convert a RJ-45 to a SFP+ port?

Thanks

Contact your ISP?
